# System-wide auto-complete word list syncing/integration?

Tags: linux, macos, text-editors, libreoffice, autocomplete

I've been thinking that convenient auto-completion is my must-have feature of the text editors and word processors that I use.  I wonder if anyone knows of a program or library that implements a system-wide rather than document-specific (or application-specific in the case of LibreOffice and others) auto-complete word list.

Comment: I don't understand the question. On OS X, just press `[Opt-]Escape` or `[Shift-]F5` in all well-behaved applications. Isn't this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are referring to LibreOffice's auto-complete feature.

The closest I found is the [english typing booster](https://fedorahosted.org/english-typing-booster/), which is a new [feature](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/english-typing-booster) in Fedora 17.

You need to compile it yourself though, if you want to use it with anything but F17.

Comment: That gives me a good place to start. Thanks for letting me know!